# Detect when a Call is unexpectedly terminated in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-telephony

I want my app to detect when a call is terminated unexpectedly, but i still can't figure a way to accomplish that.

After some research, I found the callState in CoreTelephony framework.
However, the available states are

```
CTCallStateDialing 
CTCallStateIncoming
CTCallStateConnected
CTCallStateDisconnected
```

So basically, i am able to detect when the call is disconnected but I am not able to detect if the call was disconnected unexpectedly or the user did end it.

Is there a way to accomplish my requirements?

Comment: Probably not.  The purpose for providing this information to apps is so apps can know why they have been interrupted.  Knowing how or why a call ends is not needed for that purpose.

Comment: @Avi is there a way to know the status code of the call disconnected?

Comment: What "status code" are you referring to?

Comment: @Avi the code of the disconnection. Maybe i will be then able to know the reason of disconnection

Comment: Do you have evidence such a code exists?

Comment: a `CTCall` object has 2 properties.  You can read the documentation yourself.

Comment: @Avi I meant maybe using another class other than CTCall if available

Comment: @Avi Is there a private API to detect it? The application will be an enterprise application and not submitted to the store

Comment: I have no idea.  Perhaps ask on a Jailbreak forum.